# Artifactory: Can I avoid embedded redundancies for War and Zip artifacts?

Tags: java, maven, ear, artifactory

Let's consider the following scenario

- `foo-common` is project which builds a 20mb jar (`foo-common-0.0.1.jar`)
- `foo-app1` is an application which embeds `foo-common-0.0.1.jar` in a `zip` artifact
- `foo-app2` is an application which embeds `foo-common-0.0.1.jar` in a `war` artifact
- `foo-common`, `foo-app1` and `foo-app2` are all deployed to artifactory
- `foo-app1` and `foo-app2` are managed by different teams and live in separate source repositories

This causes disk space issues on artifactory because all 3 artifacts include the 20mb `foo-common-0.0.1.jar` which ends up taking up 60mb space on disk.

Is there a smarter solution? Is there a way that `foo-common`, `foo-app1` and `foo-app2` can all live in artifactory without duplicating `foo-common-0.0.1.jar`? I'm thinking along the lines of artifactory being smarter and inspecting uploaded wars and zips for embedded jars which already exist in artifactory. Possibly by comparing file hashes or making use of maven dependency information.

Comment: If you think in Maven for EAR files that's already there (skinnyWars) but not on the repository manager site...

Comment: Thanks @khmarbaise but we can't manage this with ears. There are hundreds of teams which embed `foo-common-x.y.z.jar` inside their artifacts (wars and zips usually). Each team deploys a single war / zip to their own container.

Comment: Artifacts are standalone- you're building the zips that include the dependency. The artifacts themselves are what have the duplicates, I don't see how you could have a complete artifact that doesn't include everything required by the artifact.

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm thinking there could be a smart layer that sits between artifactory's `put` and `get` that saves some internal/private file format with pointers to shared jars

Comment: So you want artifactory to rebuild the artifact (and presumably delete it, or just stream the completed artifact) and build it back up? That's not in the scope of what it's supposed to do (or, IMO, should do). Artifacts are artifacts, monolithic blobs of data, pre-built.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, something like that... a similar process to what git does when you `put` and `get`. Consider hundreds of teams sharing the same large artifacts, it can quickly bloat artifactory and would be great if artifactory could provide a smart solution which required less disk space

Comment: You could periodically clean up the artifactory, [remove the old/unused artifacts](http://www.jfrog.com/confluence/display/RTF/Managing+Disk+Space+Usage). Not exactly a smart solution though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there isn't currently a "smarter solution".

Artifactory isn't a diff engine, binary or otherwise; it's an artifact repository. It doesn't rebuild or construct those artifacts "on-demand", it simply stores artifacts.

Comment: thanks for your input. Artifactory by it's very nature is prone to vast amounts of duplication which can amount to huge disk space requirements. It would be great if they could come up with a smarter solution which provided the same service with much lower disk space requirements. This is a difficult, but not impossible, feature to implement. Obviously sha1 checksums before / after 'smartness' should be checked for equality

Comment: As noticed, Artifactory uses deduplication, but on the file level only, not on the archive items level. Feel free to [file a feature request](https://www.jfrog.com/jira/issues/).